# Displaying the results of php document parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

Can you echo the results of a document parser or do you have to first create an array to display the results? Anyway, when running the code, nothing appears (no output or errors), and I have tried both methods. Could possibly be a site issue but I have tried a few others and get the same result.

```
<?php
$ebayquery ='halo';
$ebayhtml = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1311.R6.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X.TRS0&_nkw=' . $ebayquery . '&_sacat=0';
$ebayresults = array();

$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document->loadHTML($ebayhtml);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$links = $xpath->query('//h3[@id="lvtitle"]/a');

foreach($links as $a) {
    echo $a->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with the code.  Firstly is that `loadHTML()` takes a string for the HTML and not a filename or URI.  So first you have to read the web page and pass it in ( I've used `file_get_contents()` here).

Secondly, the XPath was looking for any `<h3>` tag with an id attribute of lvtitle, there are only instances where the class attribute is lvtitle.  I've updated the XPath expression to use this instead.

```
$ebayquery ='halo';
$ebayhtml = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1311.R6.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X.TRS0&_nkw=' . $ebayquery . '&_sacat=0';
$ebayresults = array();

$document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$ebayhtml = file_get_contents($ebayhtml);
$document->loadHTML($ebayhtml);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$links = $xpath->query('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a');
print_r($links);
foreach($links as $a) {
    echo $a->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: While your solution to the second problem worked like a charm, the first one is somewhat flawed because when executed, the url is used twice, once to get to the website, and again in the search query. So the results displayed are based on if "from=R40&trksid........" is entered in the search box.

Comment: In addition, how can the results be printed without `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 48 )` preceding the results list?

Comment: I'm not sure how the resultant page needs to be fetched, but the important part is to pass the results of fetching  the page and not the URI.  As for removing the extra output, remove the print_r from the code.

Comment: The first problem with the incorrect results being displayed was just from the wrong URL. Now everything is resolved :)